# jQuery if checkbox is checked diasble other checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have HTML code:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="all" value="all">ALL
 <input type="checkbox" name="agent" value="agent" >Agent
 <input type="checkbox" name="company" value="company">Company
 <input type="checkbox" name="branch" value="branch">Branch
```

If I check *all*, *other checkbox* becomes disabled, if I uncheck, *other checkbox* is back enabled.

I have tried doing this, using the Script below.

```
$("input[name='all']").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $("input[name='agent']").prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only do the part of disabling. You should rather use `checked` value as disabled property to toggle state based on check/uncheck status:

```js
 var subinputs = $("input[name=agent],input[name=company],input[name=branch]");
$("input[name='all']").change(function() {
   subinputs.prop("disabled",this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="all" value="all">ALL
        <input type="checkbox" name="agent" value="agent" >Agent
        <input type="checkbox" name="company" value="company">Company
        <input type="checkbox" name="branch" value="branch">Branch
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//I have added a id field in your first check box and add a class rest of checkboxes.
//This code is working you can use this

$(function(){
  $('#all_employee').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked') === true){
       $('.employee').prop('disabled','disabled');
    }else{      
      $('.employee').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="all" value="all" id="all_employee" >ALL
        <input type="checkbox" name="agent" value="agent" class="employee" >Agent
        <input type="checkbox" name="company" value="company" class="employee">Company
        <input type="checkbox" name="branch" value="branch" class="employee">Branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, there are many other ways but for your HTML this is the way yo do this

```js
$("input[name='all']").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop("disabled",true);
    }
  else {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="all" value="all">ALL
        <input type="checkbox" name="agent" value="agent" >Agent
        <input type="checkbox" name="company" value="company">Company
        <input type="checkbox" name="branch" value="branch">Branch
```

Comment: @MilindAnantwar check I have written below to enable this also and try the demo you will see it is working fine

Comment: $("input[name='all']").removeAttr("disabled");  this is the line to remove disabled attr from all  --

Comment: @krishnaveni actually this is the generic solution, how many check boxes you want to add, add you don't need to make any changes in Jquery it will work fine for n number of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Add missing else:

```
    $("input[name='all']").change(function() {
if(this.checked) {
            $("input[name='all'] input").prop("disabled",true);
}
else{
        $("input[name='all'] input").prop("disabled",false);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind a change handler, then just uncheck all of the checkboxes, apart from the one checked:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
$('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);   });
```